# GPG pinentry, how to show requestor

Tags: gpg, pinentry

So I have pinentry popping up whenever I fresh boot my desktop environment (i3), asking for my main GPG main key password. I perhaps configured at some point some program to read some pass entry, but I forgot which one and where. And nevertheless, it'd be nice if pinentry would show and tell which program is requesting the main key unlock. Is there any way to do this?